# How to install or use common build tools on agent

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I use the [YUICompressor](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/) to compress files during my TeamCity builds.  I'd like to know the best way and common practice on getting the yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar file to my TeamCity agents and where to put the file.

I am not sure if the common practice is to manually put the file on the agent machine or to somehow make the file a part of another build and use that build's artifacts.

Is there an automated way via TeamCity to push files like this to agents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity supports automatic distribution of tools to agents using the .tools folder.  Here are details: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installing+Agent+Tools

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it in repository. It is CI best practice.